# Clock disappeared from top panel. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, indicator, clock

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460.

After installing the kernel from http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/ (that should have solved another problem), the clock disappeared from the top panel.

I tried some solutions:

- restarting the system
- reinstalling `indicator-datetime`
- `killall unity-panel-service`
- reinstalling the previous kernel
- installing missing language package (I read somewhere It was working)
- via GUI, system settings -> time & date -> clock (every button is disabled)

but none of them worked.

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and I ran out of ideas. Does anybody know how to restore the clock?

Comment: Does the clock show up if you enter a guest session?

Comment: I am sorry, I kept trying random solutions and I messed up the entire system. I am installing everything again. The clock is obviously working now. Thank you